# How to select all the Data in Listbox Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

```
function SelectAll_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global p
data=get(handles.listbox3,'string');%get all the data in ListBox
set(handles.listbox3,'string',data,'value',1);%Select all
end
```

> I want to select all the data in listbox once we push the Select All Push-Button in the Same GUI

Comment: You need to adjust the [`Max` and `Min` properties of the listbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol-properties.html#property_max) to allow selection of multiple options and then set the [`'Value'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol-properties.html#property_value) accordingly. Setting it to `1` is obviously only going to select the first value.

Comment: @excaza : I tried that before. but it seems to only give me freedom to select. but it doesn't select all the data at once for processing or Display it in Guide.

Comment: Read my second sentence again. Setting `'Value'` to `1` is only going to select the first entry. You need to [create an array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) in order to select multiple values.